# Remove direct link on YouTube/Google Drive videos

Tags: youtube, google-drive-api

In order to view video on YouTube and Google Drive, I used an `iframe` on my website. But I don't want to have direct link on video (view image).

So can I remove the elements in red?

When I store my video in Google Drive, and share link by which anybody can to view it through Google Drive. Does Google Drive limit number of views or downloads per day?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be sharing the youtube link not the drive link?

It might be helpful if you post your code.

Also if you wanted to embed the video you could do that or just link them to the video with

```
<a href="youtube.video.link"><img src="your.img.png" alt="text"></a>
```

Comment: I want to remove link in "red rectangle"